# What happens if I accidentally ground the output of an LDO regulator?

Tags: short-circuit, ldo

What happens if we accidentally ground the output of an LDO regulator due to a wiring error?

In the below schematic, V+ was accidently grounded. Would this have broken the regulator?

[image]

Comment: V+ is not actually the output of your LDO. R4 (a 8.45k Ohm resistor) is between it and the ouput of the MAX6004, which would limit the "short circuit" current to something like 0.5 mA, which the MAX6004 should be able to handle.

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. Please can you edit your question and add the VIN voltage (don't post new information in comments). Also, note that it's an 'LDO voltage regulator' - LDO just stands for Low Drop-Out voltage and so isn't a name. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

You don't currently state your VIN voltage.

If your short V+ on your circuit, you're just connecting the 8.45K resistor to become a load across the regulator output.

The MAX6004 has a 4.096 V output so it will dissipate nearly 2 mW in the resistor load. That will cause the regulator no harm.

*For your reference, let's consider if you short-circuit the regulator output...*

From its [datasheet](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX6001-MAX6005.pdf), the MAX6004 regulator output itself has an output current limit. It will drive 4 mA max. into a short circuit.

The sequence of events is that the regulator will then dissipate (VIN x 0.004) W in itself, causing its temperature to rise. If the temperature can rise high enough to exceed the stated 85°C, it can stop operating reliably and above 150°C it can be damaged.

However, the datasheet simplifies this regulator calculation as it makes the following statements:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Depends on the LDO. The data sheet will actually tell you whether it has short-circuit or overcurrent protection. Modern LDOs usually do.

In the case of your MAX6004, the "ABSOLUTE MAXIMUM RATINGS" table on page 2 tells you that for input voltages < 6V, the thing is safe for an infinite duration of output shorting, and above, for 60s.

But, as Tony points out, you're never shorting the output of your LDO – you always have 8.45 kΩ  load if you short V+ to GND. That's totally harmless.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the regulator. Your MAX6004 is protected against short circuits and has a  \$ 4mA \$ short-circuit current.

[image]

However, this protection depends on your \$ V_{IN} \$ as stated in the datasheet :

[image]